# auto deployment of newly build docker image

Tags: shell, kubernetes

Every week there is a new release, and all-new docker images drop to a specific folder. My job is to do edit the Kubernetes deployments of those components, and if any new release has been done on that component, update the image name in the deployment. I want to do it automatically using a shell script, so I use the following command to copy all docker images which are saved in `.tar.bz2` format with a specific tag in another directory:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*tag*tar.bz2" -mtime -1 -exec cp {} [destination dir] \;
```

My problems are

1. finding the exact filename to use with `docker load` command
2. updating the correct component with a tag from the `.tar.bz2` file

I want to use an "if" statement to do it like below:

```sh
#! /bin/sh

 word = myword

 if [ $word = myword ]
 then 
   docker load < 
   kubectl delete svc,deployment myword -n namespace
   kubectl create -f /home/ubuntu/dockerimage/yaml/myword.yaml
fi

word = myword

 if [ $word = myword1 ]
 then 
   docker load < 
   kubectl delete svc,deployment myword1 -n namespace
   kubectl create -f /home/ubuntu/dockerimage/yaml/myword1.yaml
fi
```

This script should do the `docker load` from the `.tar.bz2` file, and as per the tag the exact image should be deployed under the exact component.

Comment: I'd generally use a Docker registry for this (either Docker Hub or something from your cloud provider) and a tool like Helm or Kustomize to create the Kubernetes manifests.  I'd avoid `docker save` and `docker load` (...on every single node in the cluster?).  Running `kubectl apply -f` with an unchanged manifest will cause no change in the cluster, and this will also simplify things (you do not need to check for differences yourself).

Comment: @NiladriDey Do you find this suggestion useful?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the reason you can't directly pull images from docker registry server in your case, your script can be improved a lot.

```
#! /bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <name>"
    exit 1
fi

word = $1

docker load < 
kubectl delete svc,deployment ${word} -n namespace
kubectl create -f /home/ubuntu/dockerimage/yaml/${word}.yaml
```

you can add some conditions to check if the file `/home/ubuntu/dockerimage/yaml/${word}.yaml` is exist and if the service and deployment of `${word}` is exist before `delete` and `create` it.

Comment: I don't need to pull docker images from the docker registry, images saved as .tar.bz2 format in local-only, I just need to load them using docker load command but every time name of the .tar.bz2 file will be different only the tag will be same, with that tag i have to run the docker load command